# Visual Studio Code is rejecting the Tensorflow installation in a Virtual Environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment called `env` using

`python -m venv env`

`.\env\Scripts\activate.bat`

`pip install tensorflow`

I verified tensorflow is in the `env\Lib\site-packages` folder

Next I loaded VS Code and created a workspace, added a python file, it prompted me to install pylint,
I typed in `python: select interpreter` and I browsed to `C:\Users\admin\env\Scripts` folder

This is the command line at the beginning of the script

```
(env) PS C:\Users\admin\env\project>  cd 'c:\Users\admin\env\project'; & 'C:\Users\admin\env\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.106424\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '54436' '--' 'c:\Users\admin\env\project\face_gan.py'
```

This is the error I get when debugging the python file:

```
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
PS C:\Users\admin\env\project> & C:/Users/admin/env/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

When I type in `pip install tensorflow` in VS Code terminal, it shows its already installed

```
(env) PS C:\Users\admin\env\project> pip install tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\admin\env\lib\site-packages (2.3.0)
```

I don't understand this, is it not running in virtual environment?
Why is it executing `C:/Users/admin/env/Scripts/Activate.ps1` at the end of the debugging session, not at the beginning

Lastly, is running python from the virtual environment folder `C:\Users\admin\env\Scripts` the same as using the `activate.bat` file or the source command? Does it automatically defer to using the `C:\Users\admin\env\Lib` folder, or is it still trying to use the default python installation to look for Tensorflow?

What step did I miss to make it use the virtual environment correct in VS Code?

Comment: What does it say in the bottom left of the VS Code status bar as the Python interpreter? It should show whether it's using the venv.

Comment: And are you able to run the file properly from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

First question: executing `C:/Users/admin/env/Scripts/Activate.ps1` after debugging command make no difference. It just because it's the first command of the terminal. You can run it again to make a try.

Second question: Yes, that's the same. In your case, it will add 'C:\Users\admin\env' and 'C:\Users\admin\env\lib\site-packages' path to the PYTHONPATH variable.

You can through these codes to get the PYTHONPATH(the default search path for module files) variable value:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If you import 'tensorflow' directly. you will find you can import it correctly. It's a version problem. You should downgrade the version of the packages, and you can refer to [this comment](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1613#issuecomment-647796774) to get some useful information.